# (Django) How to include template file from app into base.html in templates

Tags: django, django-cms

I am building a site in Django CMS. In my templates directory for the project is base.html.

I am writing an app "was_this_helpful" to add a dialog box on some pages for users to give feedback. I want to include a file from was_this_helpful/templates into base.html but it says the file does not exist.

```
{% include 'was_this_helpful/dialog.html' %}
```

My file structure look like this:

```
- was_this_helpful
    - templates
        - was_this_helpful
            - dialog2.html
        - dialog.html
    - required app files
```

I read somewhere that sometimes template files need to be another level deeper in templates to be found which is why I made the dialog2.html but still it's not working. I do not understand how to accomplish this. Based on what I've read it should work. Is it different because I'm not in another app, just the templates directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing more it's hard to tell if it's a simple solution or not.

The way you have your code written, there is not a was_this_helpful/dialog.html - you only have a dialog2.html inside your was_this_helpful so was_this_helpful/dialog2.html would be the reference path.

I've always created another folder inside my templates folder with the name of the directory above my templates folder. Just like you have with your was_this_helpful second directory. I find that this makes it much easier to extend base.html files.

You can always do it absolutely too by two periods before the path call, so ../was_this_helpful/templates/dialog.html

If you don't have luck with that either, there is an {% extends %} method as well which might accomplish what you're trying to do as well. 
Good luck!

Comment: I don't know why my subdirectory with the same name didn't work before. It seems to be now. However the base.html in my templates directory still says it's an unresolved template despite it working just fine.